# How to change character order in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, azure-sql-database

I have the string (date) "01062016" and i need it as "20160601"

Is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: char to date to char with a proper formatmask should do the trick

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for syntax for Microsoft Azure Sql Database, but you can do like this,

```
DECLARE @DateString VARCHAR(MAX)='01062016'
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Date=RIGHT(@DateString,4)
SET @Date=@Date+RIGHT(LEFT(@DateString,4),2)
SET @Date=@Date+LEFT(@DateString,2)

SELECT @Date
```

Comment: i see. Can you answer the same in Mysql db?

Comment: No Sorry @Marios ;(

Answer (score 1):

Well i figured it out.If anyone has a similar problem the solution is that:

```
select 
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),'01062016',103),5,4)+
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),'01062016',103),3,2)+
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),'01062016',103),1,2) AS DATE
```